# What is this non-detexifiable Math symbol K?

Tags: symbols

I could not detexify this:

[image]

How can you get it in LaTeX?

Comment: See Table 213: Math Alphabets of [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [blackboard bold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackboard_bold) letter, often used for number sets. Package `amssymb` provides `\mathbb`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[ \mathbb{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ} \]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]